# Java JPA - OneToOne relation breaks after updating

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have two tables (entities) named `User` and `Profile` in JPA what are syncing with MySQL database. Relation between them is `OneToOne` and bidirectional.

Here is how I made relation in model:

User:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
private Profile profile;
```

Profile:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "profile", optional = false)
private User user;
```

I am building REST API and my problem is when I update profile by his ID from controller.

Before I update data in `Profile` I am able to `getUser` from this profile.

After I update data in `Profile` (by `profileService.update(profile);`) I am not able to `getUser` for this profile.

Seems like the relation was broken.

In database there is no USER_ID on `Profile` table, just table 'User' have PROFILE_ID column.

Relation is working fine until I update it.

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Having more code might help us find what's wrong, but having too much can be harmful.

Comment: @dquijada I know but I cannot post even minimal example. It will be very large, because its big Spring REST project

Comment: Did you check if the relation persists on the database? It might be an example of you unintentionally modifying data before calling the `.update`

Comment: @dquijada 'User' table still have 'PROFILE_ID' set. But it stop working in other direction

Comment: Can you share the code of how you update the entity?

Comment: A minimal complete and verifiable example is not "your whole project code". It's minimal, complete and verifiable example, i.e. something minimal, but complete that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet I know, but how possibly REST core, model and security can be minimalistic enough to include it in post

Comment: REST and security have nothing (or at least should have nothing) to do with your problem. As you describe it, you get a profile and update it. You don't need any REST or security to do that. Writing this minimal example will help you find out, or at least pinpoint where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed problem.
It was caused by not setting User into Profile before updating, because 'dao.update()' just replacing data, not actually updating them.